# Where do I "Find Yoolis"?

Tags: x-rebirth

I'm up to the plot where my mission is to "Find Yoolis". Some teladi or something. Problem is I have no idea where to go. No mission compass, or other directions, are visible.

I am just past the part where you hack a few stations to help find her whereabouts. I had the guidance working then but I completed a side quest and now it is gone.

Does anyone know where I should go? I think it's a glitch so it should work fine as soon as I complete the next objective.

Comment: Turns out the side mission I accepted (which told me to kill a ship) took my to Yoolis's ship even though the mission guidance was on the side mission. So not the bug I thought it was but a different one.

Answer (score 1):

I asked a random ship a random question of where could find a drone dealer. It pointed me to a station. when i got to that station a dialog opened and then it led me to a ship and yoolis was there.

Comment: Hmm, well I accepted a kill side-mission... I thought it led me to a small cap ship.... might that have been Yoolis's ship? That would be awkward. But I don't think that was it. Might have to reload old save and ignore ALL side missions from then on.